# How do I memoize data denormalized with normalizr?

Tags: react-redux, normalizr, immer.js

I have a project setup with immer/redux/normalizr and it's working pretty well. My pages use connect to map some of the properties to parts of the state.

The issue I am facing is that denormalizing something with nested data will result in a complete different tree which defeats the use of immer in the first place and makes everything re-render every-time.

What is the best way to preserve the benefits of immutability and or memoize the entities in a way to output an immutable object?

If I denormalize the same thing twice, withe the same entities I get two different objects out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/normalizr-x3y1d